# Launch interactive SSH bash session from PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm using PHP to write shortcuts for common server admin tasks (I'm using deployer.org but this shouldn't be important). I want to add a task for starting an interactive bash prompt after SSHing into a server. For example, you would run "./dep ssh" (where "dep" is a PHP script) and this would have the same effect as running e.g. "ssh user@server" from the terminal. Is there a way to do this in PHP? For context, I have about 5 servers that I frequently want to SSH into, or read logs, or copy files etc. so I want shortcuts for this.

The closest I've been able to get is something like this:

```
$ph = popen("bash","w");
  while(($line = fgets(STDIN)) !== false){
      fputs($ph,$line);
 }
 pclose($ph);
```

This lets you send commands to and from bash but you don't see the normal bash prompt or get tab completion. I need something like this but with all the normal bash features working.

Comment: I'm working on a solution :). Hopefully I can finish it soon.

Comment: why don't you write your shortcuts as alias in .bashrc?

Comment: I was consistency in how I script all my tasks so all developers can easily do them. I want to be able to run "./dep ssh stage", "./dep release stage", "./del logs stage" to interactively ssh into the staging server, release and view logs respectively (the 'release' task is a non interactive set of SSH tasks for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking to do SSH in web-browser this is what you are may be looking for one of the following products:

- Google's  Secure Shell extension for Chrome and Chromium
- Anyterm
- Ajaxterm
- Gate One
- webmux
- WebShell
- EC2Box
- KeyBox
- KeyBox-OpenShift
- Mist.io

Here [is a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH) that you might like taking a look at.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but this would be a PHP script I'm running from the command line.

Comment: @fstr This means that you will have to develop it on your own, ssh2 has all the features that you need to develop a tty for bash similar to SSH utility that you use on command line take a look at [this link](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html) and start developing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
# This doesn't work, but it might lead you in the right direction.
<?
$ph = popen("bash","w");

function getCharacter() {
    $cmd = '
        read -n 1 char;
        if [ "$char"==" " ]; then
            echo space
        elif [ "$char"=="\n" ]; then
            echo newline
        else 
            echo "$char"
        fi
    ';
    return trim(shell_exec($cmd));
}

$command = "";

while (false !== ($char = getCharacter())) {
    if ($char === "space") {
        $command .= ' ';
    } elseif ($char === "newline") {
        fputs($ph, $command);
        $command = "";
    } elseif ($char === "\t") {
        # Do something fancy with the `compgen` bash utility.
        echo shell_exec("compgen -d $command");
    } else {
        $command .= $char;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's getting late so I can't finish it =D. The major problem here is reading the input (`fgets` only happens after the user enters a newline, so it can't detect "\t"). I try to fake it with `read`, but it's really buggy.

`fgetc` won't work either, that requires the user entry to be completed.

My next step would be to look into how `tty`'s work, and to try to hack it that way. But, of course, you'd still have to do a lot of work to try and make the output of `compgen` relevant. This would involve figuring out which arguments and options to send to compgen (i.e., is the user typing a command or a filename).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this ssh2](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) module in PHP, documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php).

This is how you can connect and execute your commands:

```
<?php

/* Notify the user if the server terminates the connection */
function my_ssh_disconnect($reason, $message, $language) {
  printf("Server disconnected with reason code [%d] and message: %s\n",
         $reason, $message);
}

public function my_exec_cmd($connection, $cmd) {
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd))) {
        throw new Exception('SSH command failed');
    }
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $data = "";
    while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
        $data .= $buf;
    }
    fclose($stream);
    return $data;
} 

$methods = array(
  'kex' => 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1',
  'client_to_server' => array(
    'crypt' => '3des-cbc',
    'comp' => 'none'),
  'server_to_client' => array(
    'crypt' => 'aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc',
    'comp' => 'none'));

$callbacks = array('disconnect' => 'my_ssh_disconnect');

$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22, $methods, $callbacks);
if (!$connection){
 die('Connection failed');
}else{

   my_exec_cmd($connection, "ls -la");

}

?>
```

Comment: Does this give me an interactive bash prompt though? I don't want to send a single command, I want to start an interactive bash session.

Comment: Its a programming library not a product hence it cannot be doing what you exactly wish for, you need to develop it; may be you can run it as a process keep the connection open and make a HTML page from where you can send your command requests and run them on using `ssh2` on the then server take the response back and show it on the screen and wait for the next input, thats how it becomes interactive.

Comment: Will you see the normal bash prompt? Will tab completion work? If it's not working from the example I posted I'm not sure why a specific SSH library would allow it.

Comment: No it won't allow tab completion. If you want it then there are ways to do it as well. I might have miss-understood your question because I was thinking you are looking for remotely doing a SSH from a monitoring station to your host machines, that won't work with the example you posted.